# SQL/postgres number of days in interval with filter

Tags: database, postgresql, date, join, view

(Everything I have is in postgres and I can only use db stuff and no external help)

I have the following tables:

```
Project (title, id)
Tasks   (planned_start_date, planned_end_date, contact_id, project_id)
Contact (id, contact_name)
```

Basically, a contact is assigned to a task and each task is assigned to a project.

I have to calculate the number of WORKING days which each contact has assigned per project. For example:

Projects:

- P1(proj1, 1)
- P2(proj2, 2)

Tasks:

- T1('12/12/12', '12/14/12', 1, 1)
- T2('12/12/12', '12/13/12', 1, 1)
- T3('12/12/12', '12/13/12', 1, 2)
- T4('12/12/12', '12/13/12', 2, 1)
- T5('12/12/12', '12/13/12', 2, 2)

Contacts:

- C1(1, Jack)
- C2(2, Carla)

The trick is that I also have an evaluation period which should act as a filter for the tasks start/end dates.

[image]

So I should somehow sum up all these assigned working days for a project only for the interval for which the task is inside the evaluation period.

- In this example we consider an evaluation time period from 14th of
  January to 19th of February.
- The available working days are 3 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 4 = 27 days for
  this evaluation time period.
- In this time period some tasks are "cutted" for the evaluation. This
  means that values are used pro rata:
- Task 1: not to be considered; it's outside the evaluation time period
- Task 2: to be considered in part.  planned end date (due date) -
  planned start date = 16 days (without weekends) 3 + 5 + 1 = 9 working
  days are in the evaluation phase for this Task 2. planned time effort
  pte = 6 to be done in this 16 days, i.e. 6/16 planned work effort per
  day (pte ratio) to be done (assumption of an equal distribution of
  work). for the 9 working days during the evaluation period we have a
  pro rata planned time effort of pte = 9 * (6 / 16).
- Task 3: planned time effort pte = 3
- Task 4: planned end date (due date) - planned start date = 11 days
  (without weekends) 5 + 4 = 9 working days are in the evaluation phase
  for this Task 4. planned time effort pte = 4 to be done in this 11
  days, i.e. 4/11 planned work effort per day (pte ratio) to be done
  (assumption of an equal distribution of work). for the 9 working days
  during the evaluation period we have a pro rata planned time effort
  of pte = 9 * (4 / 11).

I've used

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM generate_series(0, (end_date::date - start_date::date::date)) i
WHERE date_part('dow', start_date::date::date + i) NOT IN (0,6))
```

To get only the working days (no weekend) for an interval, but I have no idea how to sum everything up and combine everything..

Any help would be so awesome

Comment: What about the bank holidays?

Comment: They don't matter. Just weekends..